# How to prevent shell injection in setenv

Tags: c, linux, shell, setenv

I have the following simple c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setenv(key, value, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

And if execute it like below,

```
./a.out TEST $(rm /)
```

It will simply remove the root(lets assume the c binary has privilege to do so). Now I can prevent this by adding qoutes('') to the argument like below

```
./a.out TEST '$(rm /)'
```

I am trying to simulate the same inside C code(as below)but its not helping, Any idea/help on achieving this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    char key[2048] = {0};
    char value[2048] = {0};
    snprintf(key, 2048, "'%s'", argv[1]);
    snprintf(value, 2048, "'%s'", argv[2]);
    setenv(key, value, 1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The parsing of `$(rm /)` is done by the shell. You basically want to mimic `exec '$(rm /)'`. So basically want to write your own shell - at least the parsing part with the command substitution.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with `setenv` in my opinion. the `rm /` gets executed in the shell itself as a separate process. Also, the root won't be deleted even if the binary as privilege. The user executing has to have root access. The reason being again that the deletion is NOT done by the binary at all.

Comment: To put it a different way, no, there's nothing you can do to make this work. The `rm /` is executed by the shell before your program is invoked, so there's nothing the program can do to prevent or influence it.